# Who is doing the 2 up?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

In my country,

> The 2 up can be either 1 or 2 or 3 or 6

In some other countries,

> It is only 6

Who is doing the 2 up? Why?

Hint

> The "2" refers to a body part

Hint

> This is Sports related

Answer (score 5):

I think you're referring to

> American football referee scoring signals.

There seems to be

> four ways you can score;

> **1.** Touchdown - 6 points.
>  **2.** Field Goal - 3 points
>  **3.** Safety - 2 points.
>  **4.** Try after touchdown - 1 point (Field Goal or Safety) or 2 points (Touchdown)

Here's an image of

> the two type of referee scoring signals:
>  [image] [image]

We can see that in both cases

> Both of his arms are up above his head --> **2 up**.

Note:

> I'm not sure regarding the other countries where it only signals six point. Perhaps in other countries 2 arms up only refers to touchdown.

"In some other countries, it is only 6." As @Stiv points out in the comments

> I think this refers to the sport [cricket](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sportacademy/hi/sa/cricket/rules/umpire_signals/newsid_3809000/3809933.stm) where two arms up signals a "**six**".

Comment: You got the American part right.

Comment: I think the 6 you're missing relates to [this other sport](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sportacademy/hi/sa/cricket/rules/umpire_signals/newsid_3809000/3809933.stm)...

Comment: @Stiv Aah, I think you're right. l'll add that in!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the 2 up is referring to

> fingers/digits

and you are

> counting using various dactylonomy techniques

for instance

> Thumb and index = 2 in Germany
>  Thumb and pinky = 6 in China
>  Index and middle = 3 in Japan
>  Thumb and index = 1 in USA (thumb tends to be ignored unless signaling 5)